# HTML template including

Tags: javascript, html, templates

My question is for learning the most efficient way of including HTML templates in multiple HTML pages. Currently I'm trying to develop a web-site which has a lot of pages. Simple things like header&footer will be the same in all the pages. I wonder how can we implement these templates to the pages efficiently where google bot will see the page with all its content including templates.

Comment: you need a serverside template engine...pug, ejs, dust, etc are options

Comment: if you use Bootstrap you can do that. You have header. footer, and several other .php files then for each individual page you create a php with just info for that page. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: i'll use ruby on serverside not nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the CMS did use the PHP function include(), include_once(), or their variant require() and require_once(). But there are different way for using them.

Theorically, you can nest multiple sub-page this way : a main page calling a header, content, footer. The content page being just made of some include, to get i.e. homeslider page , corp overview page ... the corp overview itself being made of multiple page for each member ... to infinite.
It's up to you to find the good nesting level to achieve your goals, while staying simple.
In most classic cases, you can just set your page content (home,corp overview, team, contact) and include_once the header on top, the footer on bottom.

About Google bot, as users, it won't see the sub-page you are including this way, so there is little chance for your lone footer to be referenced.
To be sure, use robots.txt !